# Allow clicks to go through application GUI

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFx application that loads a transparent stage with some text on it.

I want any click on the application to be completely ignored and the background application (if any) to receive that click.

My code at this stage is as follows:

```
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    final StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    final Text mainText = new Text();
    layout.getChildren().add(mainText);
    mainText.setText("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||");

    final Scene mainScene = new Scene(layout);
    mainScene.setFill(null);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
    primaryStage.show();

    layout.setMouseTransparent(true);
    mainText.setMouseTransparent(true);
}
```

I was not able to achieve the requirement. setMouseTransparent() just prevented the text from triggering events, it still captured the mouse clicks.

Is it possible to achieve this in JavaFx ? Even if it is a per-OS solution.

Comment: why would you want that, looks like you want to fliter another apps input. :) thats fishy. its possible though. but why

Comment: I want to add this feature to this tool (http://bytefreaks.net/applications/on-screen-clockcount-downcounter-version-3-java), it is a widget like application that shows time. I want it to be visible, on top in a corner and to allow me to click through it so that I do not have to move it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this action in Windows is through user32.dll and Java Native Access (JNA). We used GetWindowLong to get the current configuration of the window and SetWindowLong to update the bit field that is controlling the ability of the window be transparent to the mouse.

Following is a working example that demonstrates this functionality:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    final StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    final Text mainText = new Text();
    layout.getChildren().add(mainText);
    mainText.setText("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||");

    final Scene mainScene = new Scene(layout);
    mainScene.setFill(null);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
    primaryStage.setTitle(sTitle);
    primaryStage.show();

    sUser32.EnumWindows(
     (hWnd, data) -> {

         final byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
         sUser32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
         final String wText = Native.toString(windowText);

         if (!wText.isEmpty() && wText.equals(sTitle)) {

             final int initialStyle = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(hWnd, WinUser.GWL_EXSTYLE);
             com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hWnd, WinUser.GWL_EXSTYLE, initialStyle | WinUser.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT );
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }, null);
}
```